# Unable to find File in symfony controller

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I am trying to get my uploaded images in my controller as a filetype. I am using this code to get file from my folder.

```
$oldFileNamePath = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/web/Images/10c67d8989113186c9e29a3567e5b3a2.jpeg';
$pictureFile = new File($oldFileNamePath);
```

But every time I am getting error following error

```
The file "/app/web/Images/10c67d8989113186c9e29a3567e5b3a2.jpeg" does not exist
```

I have my Images in `web/Images` folder But it is saying file does not exists

Comment: Are you using Laravel or Symfony? What version?

Comment: instead of `$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir()` try `getcwd()`. may be this will work.

Comment: @YashParekh thanky for your help `getcwd()` is working now

Comment: getcwd() is not the official recommended approach, you should use the other answer instead. https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-a-simpler-way-to-get-the-project-root-directory

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead :

```
$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../web/Images/10c67d8989113186c9e29a3567e5b3a2.jpeg';
```

the error you have here :

> The file "/app/web/Images/10c67d8989113186c9e29a3567e5b3a2.jpeg" does
>   not exist

It's true , because public files don't be accessible from the app folder . and the web folder is not inside the app folder  .

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you use absolute paths. Try to use relative paths (tries `..`) from your current file, cause I'm totally sure that your project is not in `/app`